# Unable to fill in 10x10 array with for-loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm trying to get this program to print out a 10 x 10 board of of values taken randomly from a 4 x 4 array.

All rows should be 10 entries long; for some reason some rows have been 7 and 10 entries. Other times they'll have exactly 10 each, but more often than not one or more are short. Just trying to figure out how to get this thing to print out 10 rows and columns every time. New to coding.

---

```
iostream, cstdlib, string, math.h, time.h

using namespace std;

int main()
{

srand(time(NULL));

string worldMap[10][10];

string envir[4][4] = { {"S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"}, {"P1", "P2", "P3", "P4"},
               {"F1", "F2", "F3", "F4"}, {"D1", "D2", "D3", "D4"} };

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {

        int cat = rand()%4+1;
        int subcat = rand()%4+1;
        worldMap[i][j] = envir[cat][subcat];
        cout<<worldMap[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use just `rand()%4`, without +1.

Answer (score 5):

C++ makes use of zero based indexing, you wrote `rand()%4+1` which creates a number in the range 1-4 and use it as index.

Instead this should simply be `rand()%4`

Comment: @psi I've noticed that we lately have downvoters that don't like to see simple questions being answered. Both for the questions and the answers.

Comment: That doesn't follow the guidelines. Let the question be poor, the answer, however, is correct! However, you might want to point out exactly where the error happens (when trying to access ’envir[cat][4]’) to make it very clear

Comment: @JVApen That's appalling. There's some elitism on this site which is unpleasant to see.

Comment: @john I agree, luckily I have sufficient reputation not to care too much when it happens. Maybe I should post it on Meta to get some discussion about it

Comment: The meta post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322271/is-downvoting-a-well-asked-beginners-question-ok